# How can you update a single configuration entity using drush?

Tags: drush, 9, configuration

Every now and then, if I try to import partial configs using drush, like

`drush config:import --partial --source=stuff/is/here`

drush seems to understand that some of these config entities exist in the database, and it needs to update them.

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Collection | Config                                                        | Operation |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|            | migrate_plus.migration_group.foo_migrate                      | Create    |
|            | migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_node_complete_article       | Update    |
|            | migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_taxonomy_term_article_types | Update    |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I was assuming because it noticed the `uuid` in the files matches those in the database. But if I try exactly the same command the second time, it will only say 'Create', and when I execute it, it throws an error saying they already exist.

The behaviour actually seems the same if I remove the uuid from the yml files.

I like to be able to edit, update, edit, update, without having to manually remove these entities (or reverting the database). Is that possible ? How ?

Comment: config:import --partial cannot delete, therefore you will have to manually remove

Comment: thanks. but apparently, it can update ? that would be good enough. how does it known when to update ?

Comment: yes, you can actually lookup what it does [Drush ConfigImportCommands](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/12.x/src/Commands/config/ConfigImportCommands.php) and you see it uses `Drupal\Core\Config\StorageComparer` where you find stuff like `The entity has the same file as an existing entity but the UUIDs do not match. This means that the entity has been recreated so config synchronization should do the same.`